# Why to use Hbernate @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with @OneToOne annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have a question about Hibernate One To One association. I often use the following mapping one to one association :

```
@Entity
public class Person(){

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private Address address;

//others attributes, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Address(){

@Id
private Long id;

//others attributes, getters and setters
}
```

But i see others people using :

```
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address address;
```

I look in Hibernate documentation, it's not clear for me. Someone could explain me. Why to use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with @OneToOne since the Address Entity with be mapped implicitly with it's primary key ?
Is there something, i am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn or @JoinColumn.The main difference is @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn specified that primary key of source entity is used as foreign key for target entity.
@JoinColumn (name="column_name") specified that column of source entity is used as foreign key for target entity.